# Hyper-v error starting vm after reboot

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

v host running server 2008 r2.

After reboot one of my vm is throwing following error.

'The version does not support this version of file format'

Out of my all vms this was only set to save state when shutdown.
I tried deleting state and start still same error.
Tried inspect disk as well edit disk both throw same error when try to open this.

What could it be? any way to resolve it?

Comment: I had this vhd on NAS when it was throwing this version format error. I moved it to a server and it worked. Again i moved back to san and it worked. So may be just my NAS.

Comment: After fixing it with above comment i restarted server and today started getting same thing after restart. So not sure either it's san or hyper-v. So doubt it's san and it handles thousands of files daily without any issue.

Comment: well there is a reason that MS doesn't support NAS storage for vhd's. It works but causes issues like this.  In windows 8 server they created a whole new cifs protocol for remote based vhd's.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have a corrupt VHD? Have you tried to mount the VHD using the Disc Manager in Server Manager?

How to mount the VHD:

1. Start->Control Panel->Administrative Tools
2. Double click Server Manager
3. Expand storage
4. Right Click Disk Management and select Attach VHD
5. Click browse and navigate to your VHD
6. Click Ok
7. If successfully attached, VHD could be fine. Run a disk check to make sure
8. When finished, right click the disc in Disk Managment (should be a blue icon and not grey) and select detach VHD
9. Try restarting your VM and see if the error is fixed.

Comment: Interesting never knew windows can mount vhd